How to clean ab_view_menu and ab_permission_view tables from deleted dags
We have a lot of old data in these tables from deleted dags, which are still sitting there and slowing page load when we click on security permissions tab. Is there any way other than deleting from database tables?
ab_view_menu
ab_permission_view
ab_permission_view_role
Airflow 2.7.3
Can not find cli or any official way, airflow db clean doesn't do cleaning of these tables.
